# Rethrow exception in CurrentDomain_UnhandledException?

Tags: c#, exception, unhandled-exception

When my app crashes totally, I wan't to be able to log that to check what happened after.
If I want to continue like it was uncaught, is it correct to rethrow in the `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException` event? I don't to be let my code continue as I do not know what state it is in.

So should I do this:

```
static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(
    object sender, 
    UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (logger.IsFatalEnabled)
        logger.Fatal("A fatal unhandled error occurred.", 
            (Exception)e.ExceptionObject);
    throw (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
}
```

or this?

```
static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(
    object sender, 
    UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (logger.IsFatalEnabled)
        logger.Fatal("A fatal unhandled error occurred.", 
            (Exception)e.ExceptionObject);
}
```

Comment: By the time this event is called, the AppDomain is already going to terminate.  In fact, you couldn't abort this if you wanted to.

Comment: @Dan that should be an answer, not a comment